# Hide-Show N divs with Vuejs and @click [beginner]

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-render-function

I am confused on how to hide and show 3 divs according to the click.

I have been able to show and hide 2 divs with v-show but v-show does not apply I think for more than 2 divs.

This is my code without vuejs, because I don't understand how to render with v-else-if

```
<div id="element_one">
  ONE
  <a>Go to two</a>
  <a>Go to three</a>
  Some content
</div>

<div id="element_two>
 <a>Go back to one</a>
 Some content
</div>

<div id="element_three>
  <a>Go back to one</a>
  Some content
</div>
```

app.js could be like this?

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
  isOne: true,
  isTwo: true,
  isThree: true
 }
});
```

Sorry, I understand is a basic question but if you could guide me.
I saw what there is about v-else-if in the documentation but it is still not clear to me how to apply it.
I understand that each div applies a display none to it and when it is activated it disappears.

So basically it is, that two divs are in display none when the div that I accessed through its corresponding button is activated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share your code with vue.js?

Comment: I'm not having one because, I don't know how to start, sorry :(
I only assume but It's no clear to me

Comment: you can check conditional rendering in vue

Comment: Yes, but in the examples it is very basic, like when you switch between two divs, that's why I doubt if anyone can guide me or explain what happens with v-else-if, buttons and changes between 3 divs. thank you!

Comment: I don't think there is v-else-if option. You can use v-if for all of the divs with appropriate conditions.

Comment: can you give me an example of use? thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
for using v if directive
<p v-if="inStock">{{product}}</p>
<p v-else-if="onSale">..</p>
<p v-else-if="onSale">..</p>
<p v-else-if="onSale">..</p>
and so on and the last is what`s below
<p v-else>..</>

you can also use v-show(note this toggles css property display:none)
<p v-show="showProductDetails">..</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="element_one" v-if="visibleDivId == 1">
  ONE
<a @click="showDivById(2)">Go to two</a>
<a @click="showDivById(3)>Go to three</a>
  Some content
</div>

<div id="element_two v-if="visibleDivId == 2">
  <a @click="showDivById(1)">Go back to one</a>
   Some content
</div>
<div id="element_three v-if="visibleDivId == 3">
  <a @click="showDivById(1)">Go back to one</a>
  Some content
</div>

new Vue({ 
el: '#app', 
data: {
  visibleDivId: 1,  
},
methods: {
  showDivById(divId) {
    this.visibleDivId = divId
   }
  }
});
```

You can write a function and use it to show or hide div on click.